# How to assign a new list to a nullable field if null or else just add an element to the existing list in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have an object `media` that holds `descriptions` which is a list. I'd love to see some elegant logic in Kotlin to add an element to that `descriptions` if the field is not null or add a fresh new list (with an initial element) to that field if it **is** null.

**Pseudo:**

```
if (media.descriptions == null) { media.descriptions = listOf("myValue")}
else { media.descriptions.add("myValue") }
```

Comment: Can't you show us the real code instead of a pseudo?

Comment: what do you think you gain by such a constellation? I would just initialize the `media.descriptions` to `mutableListOf<String>()` right from the beginning... except there is a really good reason you want to have it set to `null`....

Comment: otherwise there come several things to my mind... `lateinit`, `by lazy {...}`, but having a nullable list is none of them ;-)

Comment: @Roland `descriptions` can come as `null` or already with existing elements. With mutableListOf I would overwrite it I am sure

Comment: ok... someone passes you that list... and you have to add something to that list... I would probably go the other way around... you have a list that requires `myValue` to be part of it... and you add all the other values from `media.descriptions` if it isn't `null`.... and then pass your list... what about that?

Comment: Or do you try to manipulate `media` which is not fully under your control?

Comment: Your idea worked fine - thanks a heap

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would probably do it the other way around, except you need to alter `media` itself (see below), i.e. creating your list first and add all the other entries to that list if `media.descriptions` isn't `null`:

```
val myDescriptions = mutableListOf("myValue") // and maybe others
media.descriptions?.forEach(myDescriptions::add)
```

If you need to manipulate descriptions of `media`, there is not so much you can do to make it more readable...:

```
if (media.descriptions == null) {
  media.descriptions = mutableListOf("myValue") // just using mutable to make it clear
} else {
  media.descriptions += "myValue"
}
```

or maybe:

```
if (media.descriptions == null) {
  media.descriptions = mutableListOf<String>()
}
media.descriptions?.add("myValue")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Elvis operator `?:` in combination with `run`:

```
val e = "myValue"
media.descriptions?.also { it.add(e) } ?: run { media.descriptions = mutableListOf(e) }
```

- If `media.descriptions` is not null, the safe call operator `?.` calls `also` on it with the block `it.add(e)`, adding the new element to the existing list (and returning `media.descriptions` which it was passed).
- If `media.descriptions` is null, `?.` does not execute `also` but evaluates to `null`, and the Elvis operator `?:` returns its right side, executing the `run` block which initializes the field.

An alternative is always assigning (reassigning the field if it is not null), which might be less intuitive to read:

```
val e = "myValue"
media.descriptions = media.descriptions?.also { it.add(e) } ?: mutableListOf(e)
```

This works similarly, but both sides of the Elvis operator `?:` return what to assign to the `media.descriptions` field, where the left side has the side-effect (via `also`) of adding the element to the existing list.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the elvis `?:` operator to assign the list.

The simplest way I can think of is

```
media.descriptions = media.descriptions ?: listOf("myValue")
media.descriptions.add("myValue")
```

Comment: in case the list was `null` you add `myValue` twice... and still: I don't see much value of having such a nullable list in the first place...